# Are protected static properties in base classes good practice to share data between derived classes?

Tags: c#, oop, properties, static

Given the following scenario with a base class like this:

```
internal class ResolveVariableStrategyBase
{ 
    ...
    protected static EntityFieldVariable EntityFieldVariable { get; private set; }
    protected static EntityPropertyLoader EntityPropertyLoader { get; private set; }
    protected static FunctionInvoker FunctionInvoker { get; private set; }

    protected static string Variable { get; private set; }
    protected static object EntityValue { get; private set; }
    protected static object VariableValue { get; set; }
    ...
    protected ResolveVariableStrategyBase() { } 

    internal ResolveVariableStrategyBase(
        EntityFieldVariable entityFieldVariable,
        EntityPropertyLoader propertyLoader,
        FunctionInvoker functionInvoker,
        string variable,            
        object entityValue,
        object variableValue)
    { ... }

    internal virtual object Execute() { ... } 
}
```

And several derived classes like this:

```
internal sealed class RelationStrategy : ResolveVariableStrategyBase
{
    internal override object Execute()
    {
        var result = resolveRelation();
        base.VariableValue = result;

        return resolveRelation();
    }
    ...
}
```

is it really a good idea to

- have static properties in base class to spare writing the same (internal) constructor we have for the base class for all the derived classes with all the parameters setting the fields of the base class like so:

  `internal RelationStrategy(
          EntityFieldVariable entityFieldVariable,
          EntityPropertyLoader propertyLoader,
          FunctionInvoker functionInvoker,
          string variable,

          object entityValue,
          object variableValue) : base (entityFieldVariable,propertyLoader,functionInvoker,variable,entityValue,variableValue)`

or is this just laziness prioritized over well designed code?

What is an optimal solution?

Comment: It's a quick workaround, but the author of the code might have other explanations which should be heard out.

Comment: I do not have a good feeling with this code and want to know if it must be changed. I wrote it myself trying to refactor existing functionality to strategy pattern, but I am not completely lucky with it for I am not sure if those static properties are good design.

Comment: If it works, don't fix it. The KISS principle helps here, because I'm somehow fairly sure that even while you don't want to release crappy code to the client, you **REALLY** don't want to introduce new unknown bugs by unnecessary refactoring of the code that wasn't even broken.

Comment: So, if I have to make a design decision for not yet existing code, would it then be a good practice to implement it that way?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, sometimes *good practices* come in the way of quick solutions :/ I see nothing horrible in it as long as it works. But it's not perfect and could be better than having `static` members in the upper-most base class.

Comment: Instead of achieving this through inheritance, why not use composition?

Comment: This simply didn't come to my mind ;) Good point. "Favor composition over inheritance". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this is that static variables are shared across instances and across threads. This is very error prone because you have to ensure the global invariant that no two such classes may be instantiated at the same time. Also, recursive instantiations are no longer possible (arguably a more contrived scenario).

Upholding global invariants like that in a big codebase is tedious and error prone.

I usually generate the constructor delegating to the base constructor with Resharper. `Alt+Ins, Up, Space, Enter` is, I think, the key sequence to fully generate all of that code.

Maybe you can pack all those values into a DTO class so that they are easier to pass around. Resharper has great support for managing DTO classes. It can generate the constructor and initialize properties with existing constructors.

In any case I would fail that code in a code review.